# Possible number of sequences such that $x_{i} = 1$ or $ 2$ and $\sum_1^n x_{i} = 10$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How  many   finite  sequences  are  there  such  that  $x_{i} = 1$  or $ 2$ and $\sum_1^n x_{i} =  10$ $?$
Now  I  did  it  this  way:

number  of  $1$'s $\ $:$\ $  $0$ ,$2$ ,$4$ ,$6$ , $8$ , $10$   and  corresponding
number  of  $2$'s $\ $:$\ $ $5$ ,$4$ ,$3$ ,$2$ , $1$ , $0$

So  the  number  such  sequence  is  $1+ \binom{6}{4} + \binom{7}{3} +\binom{8}{2} +\binom{9}{1} + 1$ = $124$

But  the  answer  says  it  is  $89?$
Where  is  the  mistake$?$

Comment: Check your sum again.  I got $89$ using the same method you used.

Comment: Oops!  That  was  so silly,posting  it  here. Answer  did not match  and  I  thought  formula  was  wrong.

Comment: No worries.  Combinatorics are simply confusing.

Comment: By the way, if $a_k$ is the number of such sequences of length $k$, one can show quite easily (no binomial coefficients) that $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. It is easy to find $a_1$ and $a_2$. Now use the recurrence to work your way up to $10$. We get the familiar Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is right. Your algebra is wrong.

$$1+ \binom{6}{4} + \binom{7}{3} +\binom{8}{2} +\binom{9}{1} +1=89$$

Try redoing the calculation and seeing. [Link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2B%286+choose+4%29%2B%287+choose+3%29%2B%288+choose+2%29%2B%289+choose+1%29%2B1).